# fullcalendar fc-highlight covers fc-event-container background-color

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

using FullCalendar 3.9.0 when you click on a day in the calendar that is the same week as a day that has a background colour assign, the highlight div for the row covers the fc-bg div.

when week is selected:
[background hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKcqn.png)

Standard view:
[background displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mYq4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Fc-highlight-Skeleton did not have a opacity defined in the CSS, though the TD did, so I managed to solve my solution by adding:

```
.fc-row .fc-highlight-skeleton { z-index: 3; opacity: 0.3; }
```